# If a distribution and its gradient have the same finite order then the order must be zero

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory, geometric-measure-theory

As the title suggests, I would like to know whether it is possibile for a distribution and its (distributional) gradient to have the same ***finite and greater or equal than one*** order.

Comment: One can ask a slightly simpler question, on $\mathbb R$, about whether a distribution and its derivative can have the same order... avoiding some fairly irrelevant complications. :)  (Strange to me that anyone would downvote...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(There are some complications due to "support", which I think are irrelevant to the question... so I consider *compact_support* distributions...)

A compact-support distribution is a continuous linear functional on some $D_E$, meaning smooth functions on a compact set $E$. The topology on $D_E$ is the Frechet space topology from the countable collection of seminorms $|f|_k=\sum_{j\le k} \sup_{x\in E} |f^{(j)}(x)|$.

The projective limit topology (which is correct in every way...) indicates that a continuous linear functional (such as a distribution) *factors* through the topology of some "limitand", meaning that it is continuous with respect to some *finite* collection of these seminorms.

In particular, the "order/degree/whatever" of a distribution on $D_E$ is the smallest $k$ such that it is continuous with respect to the $|\cdot|_k$ topology.

It is a reasonable calculus exercise to find explicit, fairly elementary, functionals which are continuous in the $k$-th topology, but not the $k-1$...th... and so on.

EDIT: in response to a followup question... and to be more precise/explicit: if a distribution is continuous in *at_best* a particular seminorm/topology, that is exactly to declare that it is not continuous in any further.

Whatever that may exactly mean/entail, it is effectively definitional that a functional continuous in a particular topology but no finer... is not continuous in any finer.

The/any derivative operator naturally maps from one TVS to another, and the topology "loses" one degree of differentiability. Not surprisingly, considering the definition.

So, really, it's definitional (unless one somehow cannot believe that there are functions that are this-much differentiable, but not that-much...)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Paul! However, I can't see how the existence of compactly supported distributions of arbitrary order (eg the derivatives of the Dirac delta) relates to my question. What am I missing? Also, do you mean $k-1$ in the last line?

Comment: @Titti, oop, yes, you're right about the index. :) I'll repair it...

Comment: I've seen the edit. I now believe that your reasoning answers the question at least in the case of a compactly supported distributions $u$ on $R$, by using that $\frac{d}{dt}:E(R)\to E(R)$ is surjective and that, if $u'$ is (say) of order $1$, then one can write a bound of the form  $|<u',\phi>|\leq C |\phi'|_{0,K}$ (and not just with $|\phi|_{1,K}$ at the RHS) . The same reasoning should hold in higher dimension, but it is not clear to me how it generalizes to not compactly supported distributions (since $\frac{d}{dt}:D(R)\to D(R)$ is not surjective).

Comment: I am going to accept this answer because I've come to realize that the generalization to non-compactly-supported distributions is in fact trivial. This is because in the definition of order the constant $C$ is allowed to depend on the compact $K$. Therefore if there were some $u$ such that $u$ and $\nabla u$ have the same order $>0$, the same would be true for $\rho u$ and $ \nabla(\rho u)$, where $\rho$ is some compactly-supported cutoff on some $K$ ($ord(v)\leq ord(\nabla v)$ is always true). To sum up, **the claim in the title of this question is true in full generality**.

Comment: I do not understand the argument of this answer. Where exactly does it fall apart when applied to distributions of order $0$?

Comment: @Del, well, not _every_ dist'n of order 0 has a derivative of order zero. But/and we don't usually have a basic language to talk simultaneously about better-and-better functions, apart from maybe $C^k$. So, yes, for $f\in C^k$, $f'\in C^{k-1}$ in general, but sometimes it is still in $C^k$. These $C^k$'s don't really fit together smoothly with distributions of various orders (being duals!)... The $L^2$ Sobolev space version does fit the spaces and duals together in one big inclusion.

Comment: Ok so the basic fact is the following: the implication "If $u$ is of order $k$, then it is not of order $k-1$" is true for $k\geq 1$, but not for $k=0$. It leaves me kind of unsatisfied though, because one should in principle verify that for any test function one can find a primitive test function, which is not true in general (the support of the primitive could be unbounded) but it is kind of true for compactly supported distributions (one can test those with $C^\infty$, and not only $C^\infty_c$). But the latter needs some proof

Comment: @Del, I don't think the existence (or not) of primitives is the key point here... Anyway, at some point in the not-too-distant future I'd wish to make that clear...

Comment: @paulgarrett, Well, I do think that the existence of primitives is the key point here. At least, it is key in the argument I gave in the comments elaborating on your answer. Why do you say it's not?

Comment: @Titti, I am in the midst of work-related :) stuff here, but will come back to this later... Somehow I don't think the existence of primitives is the point, but, certainly I may be mistaken! :)

Comment: ... for example, on the circle, looking at $L^2$ Sobolev spaces, derivative shifts index by $1$, despite the fact that the identically $1$ function has no primitive. Looking at the spectral (Fourier series) characterization of the $L^2$ Sobolev spaces, that doesn't come into play at all. Anyway, more later...

Comment: @paulgarrett I think that the existence of primitives is a sufficient but not necessary condition. If $A:=\{\phi \in D \,|\, \exists \psi \in D \, s.t. \,\psi'=\phi\}$ is not dense in $D$, then given any $v\in D'$ of order $k\geq 1$ and any $l\geq k-1$, we should be able to find $u\in D'$ of order $l$ such that $u'=v$ (just by using Hahn-Banach, for example by letting $u$ acting as an $l$-derivative of the Dirac delta on a function in $D\setminus cl(A)$). But I can certainly be wrong (it is surely more likely that I am than you are ! :) ).

Comment: So in the case of the circle, I would argue that if it is true that the derivative shifts the index for all distributions in $D'$ (not just $L^2$) then it must be the case that $A$ is dense in $D$... Anyway, looking forward to hearing more from you when you have time.